# Database query always return true?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have been trying to make a database in *android*. The database is getting stored (I used mySQL viewer to view the database). But when I try to check for a particular entry it by using `boolean` it is always returning true.

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public void onClick(View view) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.save:
            db.addContact(new Contact(input.getText().toString(), "9100000000"));
            auth.setText("save");
            break;
        case R.id.check:
            auth.setText("check");          
            if(db.getContact(output.getText().toString())){
                auth.setText("Sucess");
            }
            else{
                auth.setText("Fail");
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

**DatabaseHandler.java**

```
// Getting single contact
public boolean getContact(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: think `SQLiteDatabase.query` never returns null; just an empty cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try making one change... Call the [getCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount%28%29) method.

```
// I think you don't need this null check, but it shouldn't hurt anything.
if (cursor != null){
  // cursor.moveToFirst(); /* I don't think you need this either. */ 
  return (cursor.getCount() > 0);
}
return false;
```